# When using ClassPathResource to create an iText image, why does getPath() result in a FileNotFound but getURL() works?

Tags: java, spring, itext7

Just something im curious about but having a hard time understanding despite reviewing itext 5.0 documentation of the Image class. When using ClassPathResource's getPath() method results in a FileNotFound but getURL() does not. When using getPath() in other instances such as loading a font file, this issue does not occur.

Comment: Your question would be improved, and more likely to get answers, by adding code examples to show how you are calling `getPath()` and `getUrl()`. And include the stack trace.